# How to Get 'request' Variable within Pipelet in Enfinity?

Tags: jsp, enfinity, intershop

I know that in Enfinity template, the `request` variable is readily supplied, and you can immediately use it. But within a Pipelet, I feel like I'm in the dark with no external variable at all except what I can access from the parameter pipeline dictionary `dict`. I need to create a Pipelet that returns client's `user-agent` into the pipeline dictionary, but for that, I need to access the `request` variable. How can I do that within a Pipelet? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The static `Request.getCurrent()` returns the IS7/Enfinity wrapped representation of the HTTP(S) request. Nevertheless this representation exposes the current servlet request (via the servlet API) which provides access to all headers and parameters transmitted between the webadapter and the app server.

Example:

```
String requestVariable= com.intershop.beehive.core.capi.request.Request.getCurrent().getServletRequest().getHeader("header-name");
```

Comment: It would be useful if you include some explanation with the code so that the OP can understand it better. Thanks.

Comment: Sure. I think that the OP will understand me well now.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to respond. Yes, thank you for this! I don't know why this is not readily available on the pipelet. Thanks!

Comment: Pipelets and pipelines should work without the servlet request context. This may be the case within a schedule or a REST request. Providing the servlet request by default binds the implementation to an active client request.